# ¿Hay un orden de ejecución dentro del "set" de un update?

Tags: sql, update

Tengo una duda que no logro resolver.

Considero un código de la siguiente forma:

```
update t 
set  t.fecha = t2.fecha, 
    t.valor1 = day(t2.fecha), 
    t.clasif1 = case when t.valor1<15 
                    then 'Si' else 'No' 
                end 
from tabla t2
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: A la hora de evaluar el nuevo valor de `t.clasif1`, el valor de `t.valor1` ¿ya será el que he puesto en la linea de encima?

Comment: Te refieres a t.valor1 = day(t2.fecha),

Comment: Primero evalúa, luego asigna. Un ejemplo más gráfico sería si hicieras "update t set t.valor1 = t.valor1 + 1". No esperarías que entrara en un bucle hasta infinito contando de uno en uno, sino que sumara 1 al valor que hay ya en la base de datos.

Comment: Para que quede claro, la respuesta es no.

Answer (score 2):

Si nos guiamos por el estándar [SQL/92](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), está bastante clara la definición:

> The `<value expression>` are effectively evaluated **before** updating
>   the object row. If a `<value expression>` contains a reference to a
>   column of `T`, then the reference is to the value of that column in the
>   object row **before any value of the object row is updated**.

Es decir:

> La expresión `<value expression>s se evalúa efectivamente **antes** de actualizar la
>   fila de objetos. Si una expresión **<value expression>** contiene una referencia a
>   una columna de`T`, entonces la referencia es el valor de esa columna en
>   la fila **antes de que se actualice cualquier valor de la fila**

`<value expression>` hace referencia a la parte del `SET` y a la asignación de valores a cada columna, `T` hace referencia a la tabla que se está actualizando.

Dicho esto, deberíamos concluir que los valores a actualizar (todos) se evalúan antes de ser actualizados. Sin embargo, los motores de bases de datos adhieren más o menos al estándar, por ejemplo, versiones actuales de `sql-server`, `postgresSQL`, `Oracle`, e incluso `sqlite` adhieren a esta definición, `MySQL` por el contrario NO, incluso está bastante bien aclarado en la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: Bien visto, MySQL tiene un funcionamiento distinto al esperado. Te dejo el enlace directo a la documentación, por si quieres incluírlo en la respuesta: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html

Comment: que raro mysql haciendo algo en contra de todas las db existentes :p